# Duplicate record created saving changes to db in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using MVC 5, EF 6.01 and Identity in Visual Studio 2013 web express.

I thought this would be a simple task of adding a history table to track changes in pricing. For each save of the parent record, two child history records are being created and not sure why. I have tried the approach below and also not using a collection (isolated history table that is updated separately).  Also tried changing the order of events in the controller.

```
 private AppDb db = new AppDb();
 private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

 public class Threshold
 {
    public int ThresholdId { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string OfficeCode { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }
    public int? Volume { get; set; }
    public int? Sort { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Threshold_History> Threshold_History { get; set; }
}

public class Threshold_History
{
    public int Threshold_HistoryId { get; set; }
    public int ThresholdId { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual Threshold Threshold { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult  Edit([Bind(Include="ThresholdId,ItemId,OfficeCode,Unit,Type,Color,Frequency,Price,Volume,Sort,OldPrice")] Threshold threshold)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(threshold).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //update history table
        Threshold_History hist = new Threshold_History();
        List<Threshold_History> histories = new List<Threshold_History>();
        hist.ThresholdId  = threshold.ThresholdId;
        hist.PriceFrom = threshold.OldPrice;
        hist.PriceTo = threshold.Price;
        hist.DateCreated =  DateTime.Now;
        hist.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        histories.Add(hist);

        threshold.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        threshold.Threshold_History = histories;

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

One note:  each Step Over in the debugger has to be clicked twice. Its almost like there are two instances of the code running at the same time.  Other modules and classes work correctly when stepping over.

EDIT to add how Edit is being called.  It is from an ajax call in a modal dialog:

```
//modal functions
 function editItem(e){
 e.preventDefault(); 
 $('#dialogContent').load(this.href, function () {
    $('#dialogDiv').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: true
    }, 'show');
    bindForm(this);
});
return false;
};

function bindForm(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');
                 loadTab(tabRef);
            } else {
                $('#dialogContent').html(result);
                $('#dialogDiv').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm();
            }
        },
        error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
            $('#modalError').html("<br><p>" + errorThrown + "</p> ");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}

function validateModal() {
var form = $(".modal-form");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
if (form.valid()) {
    form.submit();
}
}
```

Comment: You are probably calling the action twice.

Comment: How do you call Edit action? Show code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you call `validateModal()` from the submit button on the form? I don't see any `preventDefault` or `return false` so chances are that the submit button will both call `validateModal`  which causes the form to be posted and that the submit button still performs it's default function: posting the form. That would explain the duplicate calls.

If you hare handling the submit yourself, you should set the type of the submit button to "button" to prevent it from autmoatically submitting.

Comment: Yes the submit button still had a type='submit'.  I was looking for a much more complicated issue.  Feeling a bit sheepish now....

Comment: You're welcome. All problems are simple once you know the solution and the more painful the learning experience was, the easier it is to remember it (the fact that my guess was right reveals that my learning experience hunting a similar "bug" was really painful, so I've been exactly in your situation).